# Retrieve List item values from a Component using the Core Services

Tags: 2013, core-service, xml

How to retrieve List item values from a Component using the Core Services. Below is the xml.

```xml
<FaqCategory xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/tridion/schemas">
    <Title>Denied boarding compensation options</Title>
    <url>Denied boarding compensation options</url>
    <List xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:229-2468565" xlink:title="120. When will I get my voucher and where do I collect it from?"></List>
    <List xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:229-2468581" xlink:title="210. Can I upgrade my compensation ticket using my Skywards Miles?"></List>
    <List xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:229-2468568" xlink:title="140. Can I give the voucher to family or friends?"></List>
</FaqCategory>
```

In a string builder I want the output to be:

> "120. When will I get my voucher and where do I collect it from?","210. Can I upgrade my compensation ticket using my Skywards Miles?".

I tried using regex but no use. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RegEx to parse XML will probably drive you insane.

Here's a somewhat rushed way to parse your XML...

```
string xml = "<FaqCategory xmlns=\"http://www.xyz.com/tridion/schemas\"><Title>Denied boarding compensation options</Title><url>Denied boarding compensation options</url><List xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" xlink:type=\"simple\" xlink:href=\"tcm:229-2468565\" xlink:title=\"120. When will I get my voucher and where do I collect it from?\"></List><List xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" xlink:type=\"simple\" xlink:href=\"tcm:229-2468581\" xlink:title=\"210. Can I upgrade my compensation ticket using my Skywards Miles?\"></List><List xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" xlink:type=\"simple\" xlink:href=\"tcm:229-2468568\" xlink:title=\"140. Can I give the voucher to family or friends?\"></List></FaqCategory>";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string faqNs = "http://www.xyz.com/tridion/schemas";
string xlinkNs = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

XElement rootNode = xdoc.Element(XName.Get("FaqCategory", faqNs));

s.Append("Title: ");
s.Append(rootNode.Element(XName.Get("Title", faqNs)).Value);
s.Append(Environment.NewLine);
s.Append("Url: ");
s.Append(rootNode.Element(XName.Get("url", faqNs)).Value);
s.Append(Environment.NewLine);
foreach (XElement node in rootNode.Elements(XName.Get("List", faqNs)))
{
    s.Append(node.Attribute(XName.Get("title", xlinkNs)).Value);
    s.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}

Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
```